# GenSim Word2Vec unexpectedly pruning

Tags: gensim, word2vec

My objective is to find a vector representation of phrases. Below is the code I have, that works partially for bigrams using the [Word2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) model provided by the [GenSim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) library.

```py
from gensim.models import word2vec

def bigram2vec(unigrams, bigram_to_search):
    bigrams = Phrases(unigrams)
    model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences=bigrams[unigrams], size=20, min_count=1, window=4, sg=1, hs=1, negative=0, trim_rule=None)
    if bigram_to_search in model.vocab.keys():
        return model[bigram_to_search]
    else:
        return None
```

The problem is that the Word2Vec model is seemingly doing automatic pruning of some of the bigrams, i.e. `len(model.vocab.keys()) != len(bigrams.vocab.keys())`. I've tried adjusting various parameters such as `trim_rule`, `min_count`, but they don't seem to affect the pruning.

PS - I am aware that bigrams to look up need to be represented using underscore instead of space, i.e. proper way to call my function would be `bigram2vec(unigrams, 'this_report')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to further clarification at the [GenSim support forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/lsDU42VksJA/ZasFdb21HAAJ), the solution is to set the appropriate `min_count` and `threshold` values for the `Phrases` being generated (see [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) for details about these parameters in the `Phrases` class). The corrected solution code is below.

```py
from gensim.models import word2vec, Phrases

def bigram2vec(unigrams, bigram_to_search):
    bigrams = Phrases(unigrams, min_count=1, threshold=0.1)
    model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences=bigrams[unigrams], size=20, min_count=1, trim_rule=None)
    if bigram_to_search in model.vocab.keys():
        return model[bigram_to_search]
    else:
        return []
```